# Fastest square root method with exact integer result?

Tags: algorithms, integers, discrete-mathematics

I am dealing with the problem of computing $ s = \lfloor sqrt(x)\rfloor$ with $x \in [0,30000^2]$. The common `sqrtf(x)` on C language is too slow for this case, however it always gives me the correct result. I've tried with the Newton's method but I get very small errors when the square root of a number is exact. This leads to an uncertain pattern of $s-1$ results along the interval. If I increase the number of iterations the method becomes too slow but more exact.

Does anyone know of faster methods or directions on the latest research done in the area?

note to clarify: input is idealy a real number (i.e floating point) but i also accept solutions with integer as input.

Comment: How about binary search for $[x]$ in $\{0,1^2, 2^2, ..., 30^2\}$? Or a lookup table for each integer in $\{0,1,2,3,...,30^2\}$? and performing the lookup on $[x]$ (if you can afford that much memory, which does not seem much)?

Comment: What *is* the algorithm implemented in `sqrtf`? Without this knowledge, how can we tell whether [another algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/37523.37525) is superior?

Comment: Raphael, this is not a general square root, this is a square root of a number $x \leq 900$. A general algorithm is useless. As for sqrtf, it could be a (slow) machine instruction.

Comment: @Aryabhta i've already tested lookup table, it works however the lookup time takes almost the same as computing it with sqrtf() of C. On the binary search, im not sure if its better than Newton's, both of them have similar methodology, i could give it a try. By the way this computation is being performed on GPU with CUDA.

Comment: the question had a mistake on the range, now it is correct, sorry for that!

Comment: So you don't want the *conceptually* fastest method, but the one fastest on your platform in your language? In that case, you should probably ask on [SO].

Comment: I do want the conceptually fastest method as originally posted, i was just pointing out the platform as a comment, maybe shouldn't have mentioned it, if you can edit comments you might want to delete that part since it will confuse further opinions. At the moment i am looking at the work of Timothy a. Rolfe you linked to me, i think this can be useful, i still need to read it more in detail to see if their algorithm can also deal with floating point as input but integer as output.

Comment: @labotsirc, The fastest method depends on the range of the integers and on the processor. The theoretically fastest method is sometimes slowest in practice; that is the case, for example, for matrix multiplication.

Comment: @labotsirc Fair enough. In theory, the fastest method in general is certainly a lookup table (constant time). As your domain is contiguous, your hashing function is trivial (identity). In practice, you get storage problems; that's why I inferred that you were interested in practical optimality.

Comment: It would seem to me that: (1) it is difficult to be faster than `sqrtf` in practice; (2) if you have faster but sometimes off by $1$, then you can just correct it with `s=(s*s<x)?s+1:s;`.

Comment: at the moment i have managed to execute faster for the range i put. I apply Newton's method using afixed number of three iterations and adding a small **$\epsilon$** to the answer before applying the floor() function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need an exact method, anything with error less than 1 is OK. Say you want to compute $\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor$. This is the largest integer $y$ such that $y^2 \leq x$. Say you have an algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ which on input $x$ outputs $z = \mathcal{A}(x)$  such that $|z - \sqrt{x}| < 1$. You can just:

- Compute $z = \mathcal{A}(x)$
- Let $z_0 = \lfloor z \rfloor$
- Let $S = \{z_0 - 1, z_0, z_0 + 1\}$
- Output  $y = \max\{y \in S: y^2 \leq x\}$ (in words: output the largest integer among $z_0 - 1$, $z_0$, $z_0 + 1$ whose square is at most $x$).

You can also verify you have the correct number by checking that $(y+1)^2 > x$.

Correctness follows from the fact that if $|z - \sqrt{x}| < 1$, then $|\lfloor z \rfloor - \lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor| \leq 1$.

I think Newton's method with a small number of iterations is the best thing you can do. Since you only need error smaller than 1, I believe a few iterations will indeed suffice. Doing extra three integer multiplications and comparisons at the end cannot slow you down so much.